# Update Button UI on press SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a view that contains a list of buttons, each button representing a player. My goal is to add a player to the team when their respective button is pressed.

```
struct AddPlayers: View {
    var team: Team
    var playerData = getPlayers()

    var body: some View {
        List(playerData) { player in
            Button(action: {
                addPlayerToTeam(teamID: team.id, playerID: player.id)

                // update the PlayerRow to show player was added to team
            }) {
                PlayerRow(player: player, team: self.team)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Players"))
    }
}

struct PlayerRow: View {
    var player: Player
    var team: Team

    var body: some View {

        let view = HStack {
            Text(verbatim: player.FirstName)
            Text(verbatim: player.LastName)

            Spacer()

            // displays true if player is on the team
            if playerInTeam(team: team, player: player) {
                Text("True")
            }
        }

        return view
    }
}
```

I am able to add the player to the team when pressed, but I have not figured out how to update the UI. Currently, if I close the app and reopen it to force reload the UI then it shows "True" on the correct players.

I have tried to make `playerData` a `@State` variable and update `playerData` every time a button is pressed. This causes the line `PlayerRow(player: player, team: self.team)` to run however the body of `PlayerRow` is never entered and therefore the UI is not updated.

```
struct AddPlayers: View {
    var team: Team
    @State var playerData = getPlayers()

    var body: some View {
        List(playerData) { player in
            Button(action: {
                addPlayerToTeam(teamID: team.id, playerID: player.id)

                // attempt to force reload the List
                playerData = getPlayers()
            }) {
                // called due to playerData = getPlayers()
                PlayerRow(player: player, team: self.team)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Players"))
    }
}

struct PlayerRow: View {
    // this sections is run due to playerData = getPlayers()
    var player: Player
    var team: Team

    var body: some View {

        // code does not enter here
        let view = HStack {
            Text(verbatim: player.FirstName)
            Text(verbatim: player.LastName)

            Spacer()

            // displays true if player is on the team
            if playerInTeam(team: team, player: player) {
                Text("True")
            }
        }

        return view
    }
}
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue related to updating a button image on button press in swift UI. Did you find solution for your question?